# Transforming to 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization

I need to reduce a model DB to 3NF. However there is a column in the data thats very ambiguous.

So the database has the following columns. (Apologies for formatting, I did try)

```
Employer ID | ContractNo | Hours | emp Name | workNo | workLocation
--       
123         | A1         | 10    | J Smith  | W36    | New York 
124         | A1         | 7     | P Jones  | W36    | New York 
125         | A2         | 9     | R Lewis  | W37    | Los Angeles 
123         | A2         | 9     | J Smith  | W37    | Los Angeles
```

Each employee has a unique ID, an employee can work at more than 1 location and each location has a unique workNo. I'm just a bit stuck on where to include the ContractNo. There is no indication in the question of what it actually is for.

So my first step was splitting it up into a table with EmployerID, employee Name and hours. And a second table with WorkNo, WorkLocation. But what do I make of that bloody ContractNo?

Comment: Before you can normalize a relation, start by identifying and listing the functional dependencies that apply.

Comment: What reference are you using for normalization? Your question is not consistent with knowing what normalization is.

Comment: Is the first column "Employer ID" or "Employee ID"?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the contract is likely a separate entity, capturing the nature of the relationship between contractor and contractee.

[image]

Image from [QuickDBD](https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/schema/l1CxEzxfA0iht5i4ocGZiw), where I work.

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by others that are projections of it and join to it. It does not introduce new columns.

Comment: Very true!  I introduced the new columns to establish a naming standard in the little schema, particularly for keys. I couldn't bear to use `emp Name` as a primary key for example :) Sorry if that distracts from my main point: introducing the Contract table.

Comment: The question is about normalization to 3NF, and this answer (like the question) doesn't reflect an understanding of what that is. See the comments on the question.